# Show the Angular-chart-js pop up information hidden overflow

Tags: angular-chart

i am trying to make the pop up information that angular-chart-js provides visible in its full lenght. My problem is as follow: I have mi charts inside a bootstrap defined column, usually when you hover over the chart you get the pop up information but, in my case, there is not enought space for this pop up to be fully visible due to the reduced space of the bootstrap column. Is there a way to make this information overflow visible exceeding the column size?.
I am sorry about my english not being that good.

Comment: Do you have some code to show ?  That helps.

Comment: This one is an old question and i already finished that proyect, i forgot about deleting it, thanks anyway!!